# Are "what does everybody believe about X?" questions still off-topic?

Tags: discussion

It's been a while since I was last active on this Stack. At one time it was the rule that a general "what does everyone believe about X?" question was off-topic. Rather, people had to specifically ask "what does Y believe about X?" using both tags and specifying the restriction in their title and question. Is this still the case?

Comment: Yeah, that's an overview question - it's OK to ask - but make sure you flag answers if they're not representative of a large swath of Christianity, we expect all the answers to be complete, so nobody just throws in a standalone anabapist perspective  at the end